# Multiple domains for scale in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gantt-chart

I want to create this type of label using d3.js:

```
70008 a
      b
      c

70009 a
      b
      c
```

Is this possible?

Currently I create the y axis like this:

```
y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(taskTypes).rangeRoundBands([0, SetSVGheight() - margin.top - margin.bottom], .1); 
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0);
```

Here is my data array:

```
{startDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:05:39.000' ),endDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:07:23.000' ),taskTypes: '72000',type : 'downtimes',dto_color : '#0000FF',},
{startDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:05:39.000' ),endDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:07:23.000' ),taskTypes: '72000',type : 'orders',dto_color : '#f2f2f2',},
{startDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:05:39.000' ),endDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:07:23.000' ),taskTypes: '72000',type : 'teams',dto_color : '#aaaaaa',},
{startDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:07:23.000' ),endDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:08:15.000' ),taskTypes: '70100',type : 'downtimes',dto_color : '#FF0000',},
{startDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:07:23.000' ),endDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:08:15.000' ),taskTypes: '70100',type : 'orders',dto_color : '#f2f2f2',},
{startDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:07:23.000' ),endDate : new Date( '2015-01-15T15:08:15.000' ),taskTypes: '70100',type : 'teams',dto_color : '#aaaaaa',},
```

How I can add additional domain to y axis?

Comment: The link to the picture was broken, so I removed it for now, but feel free to add it back in once you have a working one. Also, if you put this code into a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/), it will be a lot easier for people to help you and you'll be more likely to get answers.

Comment: I don't understand the question.